# TypeScript: Implicit number to enum cast

Tags: casting, typescript, implicit-conversion

Why does the following compile in TypeScript?

```
enum xEnum {
  X1,X2
}

function test(x: xEnum) {
}

test(6);
```

Shouldn't it throw an error? IMHO this implicit cast is wrong here, no?

Here is the [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=enum%20xEnum%20%7B%0A%09X1%2CX2%0A%7D%0Afunction%20test%28x%3A%20xEnum%29%20%7B%0A%09console.log%28x%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atest%286%29%3B).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is part of the language specification (3.2.7 Enum Types):

> Enum types are assignable to the Number primitive type, and vice
>   versa, but different enum types are not assignable to each other

So the decision to allow implicit conversion between `number` and `Enum` and vice-versa is deliberate.

This means you will need to ensure the value is valid.

```
function test(x: xEnum) {
    if (typeof xEnum[x] === 'undefined') {
        alert('Bad enum');
    }
    console.log(x);
}
```

Although you might not agree with the implementation, it is worth noting that enums are useful in these three situations:

```
// 1. Enums are useful here:
test(xEnum.X2);

// 2. ...and here
test(yEnum.X2);
```

And 3. - when you type `test(` it will tell you the enum type you can use to guarantee you pick one that exists.

Comment: ok, thx for pointing that out. Is this a wise decision? I mean, in this case, the enum type has no use at all.

Comment: It is wise in the sense that you mostly work with web servers and then its just a number

Comment: I have added three cases where enums are better than numbers. I know if doesn't cover your case (and it could do if the language spec was changed to remove the implicit `number` -> `enum` conversion) there are still some useful reasons to use it. They aren't "bad", just "not as perfect as you'd like" :)

Comment: @SteveFenton: don't get me wrong, I want to use enums for exactly those reasons you mentioned. I'm just disappointed, that you can plug in any number as an argument, and circumvent the type-check.

Comment: You could propose the change over on GitHub - you never know, you might get a lot of support for removing that implicit cast :) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: @basarat: True. On the other hand, you could also argue to implicitly cast a string to an integer, since web servers send strings. If we want that, we probably wouldn't use TypeScript in the first place, would we? I probably open a request as SteveFenton suggested :)

Comment: @SteveFenton I think you have a half true here. It's not about implicit conversions or type casting, it's about the value not being found in the set of constants. enum xEnum {X1=6, X2} ruins it for test(0).

Comment: @itmitică that's right - but if the implicit conversion from `number` to `enum` was removed, it would encourage people to substitute `test(100)` with `test(xEnum.X2)`. Of course, someone really stubborn might attempt `test(<xEnum><any>100)` - but you can commit a lot of crimes if you tell the compiler something is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't. There is no type casting here, the base type behind them all is the same, integer.

[typescript enum type checking works fine](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=enum%20xEnum%20%7B%0A%09X1%2CX2%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20test(x%3A%20xEnum)%20%7B%0A%09console.log(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atest('6')%3B%0A)

Your complaint is about range value which, in this case, has nothing to do with type checking.

[enum is a flexible set of constants](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=enum%20xEnum%20%7B%0A%09X1%3D6%2C%20X2%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20test(x%3A%20xEnum)%20%7B%0A%09console.log(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atest(6)%3B%0A)

```
enum xEnum {X1=6, X2} // ruins it for test(0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ruin"? The code works perfectly, no errors raised.