# Incompatible enum value isn't detected

Tags: typescript

I want to define the type of a property in an interface to be equal to some values of a Enum.

No control is done with Enum. But if I replace the compatible Enum values with their real values, the control is done.

Can you see a solution?

```
enum Type {
    one = 1,
    two = 2
}

// --------------------------------

interface CheckType_KO {
    type: Type.one | Type.two // <--- I want to define the type like that
}

let bad_compatibility_check: CheckType_KO = {
    type: 4 // <--- it's a bad value, but there is no error ! >>>> KO
}

// --------------------------------

interface CheckType_OK {
    type: 1 | 2 // <--- the the real value directly
}

let good_compatibility_check: CheckType_OK = {
    type: 4 // <---- the bad value is detected
}
```

You can test the code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Type%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20one%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20two%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20--------------------------------%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CheckType_KO%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Type.one%20%7C%20Type.two%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bad_compatibility_check%3A%20CheckType_KO%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%204%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20--------------------------------%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CheckType_OK%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%201%20%7C%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20good_compatibility_check%3A%20CheckType_OK%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%204%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A#src=enum%20Type%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20one%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20two%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20--------------------------------%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CheckType_KO%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Type.one%20%7C%20Type.two%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bad_compatibility_check%3A%20CheckType_KO%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%204%20%2F%2F%20bad%20type%20BUT%20NO%20ERROR%20%3E%20KO%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20--------------------------------%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CheckType_OK%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%201%20%7C%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20good_compatibility_check%3A%20CheckType_OK%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%204%20%2F%2F%20bad%20type%20AND%20ERROR%20RETURNED%20%3E%20OK%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

Answer (score 2):

In typescript enums are basically numbers, so even this won't have a compilation error:

```
let a: Type = 22;
```

So basically `Type.one | Type.two` is `number`, while `1 | 2` stays `1 | 2`.

Here's another thread that is talking about it: [Implicit number to enum cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762823/typescript-implicit-number-to-enum-cast)

If you want to have type safety with enums then you'll need to use the actual enum, for example:

```
enum Type {
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3
}

interface CheckType_KO {
    type: Type.one | Type.two;
}

let bad_compatibility_check: CheckType_KO = {
    type: Type.three
}
```

Has the following compilation error:

> Type '{ type: Type.three; }' is not assignable to type 'CheckType_KO'.
>   Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>   Type 'Type.three' is not assignable to type 'Type.one | Type.two'.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is, for my case, to not use Enum, but Type:

```
type ONE = 1
type TWO = 2

interface CheckType_OK2 {
    type: ONE | TWO
}

let good_compatibility_check2: CheckType_OK2 = {
    type: 4
}
```

with this code, Typescript compiler throws an error, that is what I want to "make illegal state unrepresentable". ;-)