# Using enums as types allows values that don't exist in the enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I have this typescript code ([typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20const%20enum%20Something%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Email%20%3D%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20All%20%3D%2020%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20enum%20Other%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Email%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Value%20%3D%2015%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20Something%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20value2%3A%20Something%20%3D%20Something.None%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Why%20can%2015%20be%20assigned%20if%20it's%20not%20in%20the%20enum%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20value%3A%20Something%20%3D%2015%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20These%20error%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20otherValue%3A%20Something%20%3D%20'asdf'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20value3%3A%20Something%20%3D%20Something.NotExists%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20value4%3A%20Something%20%3D%20Other.Value%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20value5%3A%20Something%20%3D%20Other.Email%3B)):

```
const enum Something {
  None = 0,
  Email = 10,
  All = 20
}

const enum Other{
  Email = 10;
  Value = 15;
}

interface Foo {
  prop: Something
}
const value2: Something = Something.None;

// Why can 15 be assigned if it's not in the enum?
const value: Something = 15;

// This errors:
const otherValue: Something = 'asdf';

const value3: Something = Something.NotExists;

const value4: Something = Other.Value;

const value5: Something = Other.Email;
```

I don't understand why 15 is an acceptable value in this caase. 15 is not a value of the enum, so shouldn't it throw?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168952/what-is-the-significant-of-enum-in-typescript/49169301#49169301

Comment: I believe that this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762823/typescript-implicit-number-to-enum-cast

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>(update 2021-06-10, this is unchanged by [the TS4.3  update for union enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#union-enums-cannot-be-compared-to-arbitrary-numbers))</sup>

This is (maybe surprisingly) intended behavior.  Numeric enums in TypeScript are sometimes used for bitwise operations, where the listed values are treated as [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Flags_and_bitmasks).  And, as stated by [@RyanCavanaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704166/ryan-cavanaugh) in a [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8020#issuecomment-208717449) on a [reported issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8020) about this:

> We don't distinguish between flag and non-flag enums, so a number that is above [or not equal to] any given enum member isn't necessarily invalid. For example

`enum Flags {
Neat = 1,
Cool = 2,
Great = 4
}
// like saying Neat | Cool | Great
var x: Flags = 7;`

So even though `7` is not equal to any one of the listed `Flags` enum values, you can still get it by performing bitwise operations of the listed values.  I'm pretty sure that the compiler doesn't do *any* restriction other than checking that the value is a `number`.

In your case, even though none of the `Something` enumerated values are `15`, it doesn't stop you from doing the (useless and dubiously sane) following:

```
const value: Something = (Something.Email | Something.All) >> 1;
```

which amounts to the same thing (`10 | 20` evaluates to `30`, and `30 >> 1` is `15`).

---

Note that this bitwise stuff doesn't apply to *string-based* enums, so one way to deal with this is to change your numbers to string literals:

```
const enum Something {
  None = '0',
  Email = '10',
  All = '20'
}
const value: Something = '15'; // error, as desired
```

and the compiler warns you that `'15'` is not a valid value for `Something`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks -- compiler in that case does indeed warn that '15' is not assignable to type 'Something', but it also complains that '20' (or '0', or '10') is also not assignable to type 'Something.'  

And if you try `const value: Something = 'XXXX' as Something` it doesn't complain at all, no matter what the value. Confounding!