# How to use Typescript enum as function parameter?

Tags: typescript, enums, parameters

I'm struggling to get type safety when using enum as function parameters. For example, using the example code in the [TS Enum docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

```ts
enum UserResponse {
  No = 0,
  Yes = 1,
}

function respond(recipient: string, message: UserResponse): void {
  console.log(recipient, message)
}

respond("Princess Caroline", UserResponse.Yes);

respond("Princess Caroline", 'some other message'); // Argument of type '"some other message"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserResponse'.

respond("Princess Caroline", 5); // No error...
```

- Why is the compiler not giving errors when using the value `5` which is not defined in `UserResponse`?
- How can I improve the typings so that the `message` param ONLY accepts `UserResponse.Yes | UserResponse.No`?
- Should I be using some other data structure to hold `UserResponse`?

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198352/3388225) answers your question in good details.

Answer (score 0):

This question is unfortunately a duplicate. However, that means there's already an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49169301/12425097 - It looks like your best bets are to use a string enum, or a namespace type union which is demonstrated in the linked answer.